# Change values of column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i'm working with a dataset.
One of the columns is the age, but it comes in days, the type is 'int64'.

I need to convert this column to years. (Make the divison by 365)
So, i tried, to change the type of data, and still not working, give the error "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'" or "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'age'" and other.

Someone can help me?

Comment: please show a minimal reproducer code

Comment: You probably need to cast your `'age'` column from `str` to `int`. Try `your_dataframe['age'].astype(int) / 365`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is mainly due to data type mismatch of the column. It could be that age column contains some string format values too. Before dividing by 365, convert the age column to numeric format using astype function below :

df['age column name'] = df['age column name'].astype(float)

If the above code results in error that means somewhere in the columns there are some string format values that cannot be converted to numbers.

Once the above code runs successfully, you can divide the column by 365.

Comment: One thing. How can i remove '.0', from the output?

Comment: you can try using round function or post division convert the type back to int64